# How to convert .py file to executable file to run in linux

Tags: python, windows, binary

On my windows PC, I created a python script. Now, i want to run this on LINUX machine. Using pyinstaller,I can able to create exe file. But, how can I create an executable file on windows pc, which should run in linux machine.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Look at this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425394/how-can-i-get-a-binary-from-a-py-file

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. If you are writing python script in windows machiene, you can create only windows executable files. If you are writing python script in linux, you can create executable shell file to run on linux. From linux machiene, one cannot create exe file to run on windows.